# Monotonically Increasing Mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

$\mathbf{h}_1, \mathbf{h}_2\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ are given column vectors and $a>0$ is a given constant. Consider the matrix $$\mathbf{A}(x)=\mathbf{I}+x\mathbf{h}_1\mathbf{h}_1^{\text{H}}+\left(a-x\right)\mathbf{h}_2\mathbf{h}_2^{\text{H}}$$
If $x$ is gradually increased from $0$ to $a$, is it possible to say anything about the behaviour of $\mathbf{h}_1^{\text{H}}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{h}_1$, i. e. monotonically increasing or decreasing? I tried taking derivative with respect to $x$  and then using the C. S. inequality. But it didn't really help. After taking derivative and some simplification, I get an expression like 
$$\mathbf{h}_1^{\text{H}}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\left(\mathbf{h}_2\mathbf{h}_2^{\text{H}}-\mathbf{h}_1\mathbf{h}_1^{\text{H}}\right)\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{h}_1$$
But I am stuck at this.

P. S. It's part of an optimisation problem I am trying to solve. I have in fact plotted a few cases and found it to be monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By performing a unitary transformation, you can always assume that $\mathbf{h}_1=r\mathbf{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{h}_2=p\mathbf{e}_1+q\mathbf{e}_2$ where $\mathbf{e}_1$ and $\mathbf{e}_2$ are the first two vectors in the canonical basis. Then straightforward calculations show that
$$
\mathbf{h}_1^{\text{H}}\mathbf{A}^{-1}\mathbf{h}_1=
\frac{r^2[1+q^2(a-x)]}
{[1 + r^2x + p^2(a-x)][1+q^2(a-x)] - p^2q^2(a-x)^2},
$$
which is a rational function of $x$. This is not always monotonic. For example, when $a=1,\mathbf{h}_1=(2,2)^H$ and $\mathbf{h}_2=(4,2)^H$ (or $\mathbf{h}_1=\sqrt{2}(2,0)^H$ and $\mathbf{h}_2=\sqrt{2}(3,1)^H$ after rotating $\mathbf{h}_1$ to align with $\mathbf{e}_1$), you get a U-shaped curve.